Understanding the Universal Properties and Definitions of Thom Spectra
I've been trying to understand the definitions and universal properties of Thom spectra, but I'm getting lost in the various perspectives and the connections to the geometrical story.
Given a space $X$ and a map $f: X \to \text{Pic}(\mathbb{S})$, I know we can define Thom spectra in different ways:

As a colimit.
Using the counit of the adjunction:
$$
\text{Pre}: \text{CAlg}(\mathcal{S}) \rightleftarrows \text{CAlg}(\text{Pr}^L): \text{Pic}
$$
which gives a map
$$
\mathcal{S}_{/\text{Pic}(E)} \to \text{Mod}_E
$$

Moreover, for an $E_\infty$-ring spectrum $E$, an $X$-orientation on $E$ is defined as a trivialization of the composition:
$$
X \to \text{Pic}(\mathbb{S}) \to \text{Pic}(E)
$$
This allows us to define the Thom spectrum $M_f$ as classifying $X$-orientations, in the sense that
3. There is an equivalence between maps $M_f \to E$ and $X$-orientations on $E$.
We can also ask about conditions under which the Thom spectrum is an $E_\infty$-ring (or more generally an $E_n$-ring).
My main interest is in understanding the connection between the colimit definition of Thom spectra and the description in terms of trivializations. I wonder if the adjunction perspective could help clarify this relationship (and the $E_n$ strcture discussion).
I've come across papers by Ando, Blumberg, Gepner, Hopkins, and Rezk (e.g., "Parametrized Spectra...", "Units of Ring Spectra..."), but I’m having trouble pinpointing where exactly the big picture emerges or how to extract the essential details from them.
I also read this MathOverflow question, which explains the pushout perspective on Thom spectra. However, it doesn't fully clarify the relationship between the colimit definition and the trivialization perspective.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light on this topic, even in the form of a brief overview or personal insight into how these different constructions relate. Any pointers to notes, talks, or other resources that explain the "zoo of Thom spectra" and their connections would be very helpful.
